# Who is that guy in Mind Hunter every episode?

Tags: character, mindhunter-2017

In the TV show *Mindhunter* there is a nerdy looking guy who appears briefly before every episode starts (or most episode starts). He is seen showing some eccentric and anti-social behaviors.

How is he related to the plot?

I have this feeling that they are building up suspense for season 2 or even season 3, but I want to be sure.

This TV show is relatively realistic, a few murderers from it are based on actual murderers, is this mysterious nerdy guy one of actual murderers?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Warning: Spoilers

Keen watchers of the show who also know their serial killer history have identified him as:

> Dennis Rader, a.k.a. [The BTK Killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Rader)

Likely his small cameo moments during season one are building him up to become either the primary...

> villain

...of season one, or to have the show follow his story arc in season two.

This link is made because the show is set in 1977, and:

> Rader worked at the Wichita-based office of **ADT** Security Services from **1974 to 1988**, where he installed security alarms as a part of his job, in many cases for homeowners concerned about the BTK killings.

This is explained in more depth [here](https://www.popsugar.com/entertainment/Who-ADT-Guy-Mindhunter-44145236) (SPOILERS!!)